# How does a very small number behave while processing?

Tags: java, types, processing, primitive-types

Well I am working on a big dataset and after some calculations I am getting values for the features like 4.4E-5. I read it somewhere those values means 0.000044 that is ten to the power minus 5. So my question is whenever I want to use them for further processing will these values behave same as float works or do I need some other data type?

Comment: What type are they now? How much precision do you require?

Comment: This isn't clear; if your data-type is `float`, then it will behave like `float`!

Comment: yes my data type is float only so i can assume them as float itself and proceed right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an extended notation presenting the same binary floating point data type.
Both 4.4E-5 and 0.00044 are the same. And that value only approximates 0.000044 with a sum of powers of 2: 2^-18 + ...

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying lots of small numbers leads to underflow. Take the `log` and add. This technique is universal in computer science. Many of the Google hits for ["underflow log"](https://www.google.com/?q=underflow%20log#q=underflow+log) are useful, including SO hits, other techniques for dealing with it, etc.

Comment: You mean take a log of 4.4E-5 ?

Comment: Yeah that's around -5, right? (You can use common or natural log). Pretty reasonable number to do computations with.